# Set Theory -- set theoretic mathematical representation

Tags: notation

I am trying to convert this description into set theoretic mathematical representation but I am having some trouble. Any help would be appreciated

S3: The set containing all pairs of natural numbers, i.e., 2-tuples like
(a,b), such that the second element of the pair is twice the first.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about $\{(a,b)|a,b\in\mathbb N, b=2a\}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `computability`?

Comment: You should also indicate what you have tried, and also what notation conventions you may be using.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as
$$
\{(n,2n) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$

Comment: Would the downvoter dare to explain his vote?

Comment: +1.... To the proposer: You can also use $\,:\,$ instead of $\,|\,$, as $\{(n,2n): n\in \Bbb N\}$, which helps if you need to mention absolute values as well. E.g. $\{x\in \Bbb R: |x|>3\}.$